# Find all directories NOT containing matched subdirectory and create them

Tags: directory, directory-structure, mkdir

I have the following directory structure:

```
/media/storage/sqlbackup/CUSTOMER1
/media/storage/sqlbackup/CUSTOMER2
...
/media/storage/sqlbackup/CUSTOMER*
```

Each `CUSTOMER*` directory *may* contain subdirectories named `daily`, `weekly`, and `monthly`. If a `CUSTOMER*` directory does not contain `daily` OR `weekly` OR `monthly`, I want it to be created, if it does, then I want it to remain.

Before:
`CUSTOMER1/daily`

After:
`CUSTOMER1/{daily,weekly,monthly}`

I was trying to do this with clever use of find, but trying to return all that don't match.

Comment: What do you want created if there are no `daily`, `weekly`, `monthly` directories for a given customer? All of them? Just one? Which one?

Comment: So you want to create all missing subdirectories?

Comment: Yes, @roaima. Correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create the directories while hiding any error related to the directory already existing:

```
for custDir in /media/storage/sqlbackup/CUSTOMER*
do
    mkdir -p "$custDir"/{daily,weekly,monthly}
done
```

You cannot use `/media/storage/sqlbackup/CUSTOMER*/{daily,weekly,monthly}` because the `{...}` sequence is expanded before the wildcard, and a wildcard pattern will only match files/directories that exist.